# Godot Particles Randomly Turn Off

Tags: particles, godot

I have a particle emitter on a rocket just to simulate some smoke. The rockets can be free-fired or lock onto a target and gradually steer towards the target. There is an issue that I can't seem to fix. When the rockets steer too sharply from their original trajectory the particle emitter turns off. Printing `trail_particles.emitting` shows `true`. GIF illustrating this issue:

[image: Gif]

I can share code, though I'm not sure which part would be relevant since I don't access the particle emitter in code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Godot, but in other engines this can occur if the bounding volume of the particles is inaccurate, leading the engine to believe the particles should be completely off-screen, so they get pruned out by frustum culling. I'd recommend looking into any options relating to providing or recalculating bounds that might be offered here.

Comment: @DMGregory - Possibly, since if the rockets are circling something the particles seem to come back on, then turn off, then come back on, etc. I'm looking into it but I've never worked with particle systems prior to this so it's all brute force at this point. The particle emitter is bound to the rocket so it should keep rotation and alignment with the rocket.

Comment: This could be back-face culling related. Is your particle geometry material billboard parameter enabled?

Comment: Maybe try to add a new camera to the scene that you use to watch through to see the rockets from different angles? Or possibly even easier just spawn some rockets flying different directions relative to where you are looking.